# Is it possible to hybrid boot(fast startup) ubuntu like windows 10?

Tags: boot, suspend

In windows 10 with fast startup enabled, the computer does not completely shut down and boots very fast (even without SSDs).

Is there any similar feature available in ubuntu which will make its startup very fast without requiring any power in the background (while shut down) ?

Note: Hibernation does not seem to decrease start up time. It does not seem to impart any change at all compared to normal shutdown.

Comment: You can Hibernate. http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/add-hibernate-option-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Does that consume no power?

Comment: Windows uses hibernation, On large RAM and HDD it is slow too.

Comment: Waking up from hibernation is as slow as cold startup

Comment: That's because RAM is too big. It takes lots of time to read it from HDD.

Comment: The main difference I see starting up from hibernation is that everything that was running before hibernation is running after restarting. I find it faster than a cold start for sure. Is your swap file/partition large enough?

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi: If I hibernate and then unplug the computer and then plug it back in, everything resumes OK. I would assume this means that no power is used for hibernation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no comparable feature to Windows Fast Startup available in Ubuntu.**

By 'comparable feature', I mean hibernate that is (deliberately) used in place of poweroff in order to speed the poweron/boot experience for users. Many (not all) users can enable Hibernate on their Ubuntu system, which will achieve most of the same effects as Fast Startup...but the OP has already rejected hibernate in the Question as a useful solution.

Ubuntu developers work very hard to minimize startup time while keeping the boot cycle simple enough for the community to support. All kinds of techniques are used (ureadahead, compressed kernels, systemd targets, etc.) to minimize the amount of (slow) IO activity, and get you to login as fast as possible.

And it works: Boot tends to be much faster than it was 10 years ago.

Users who need help diagnosing problems or delays with their particular system's boot are welcome to open a new question.

Community volunteers are welcome to help test boot improvements in the next pre-release version of Ubuntu.

Developers who have a new, supportable technique to improve boot are welcome to bring it to the dev channels. Ubuntu developers are happy to listen to new ideas.