# Does Ubuntu 20.04 have an equivalent to Windows' Fast Startup?

Tags: boot, 20.04, shutdown, windows-10, hibernate

Windows 10, esp. on SSD, can boot really fast, partly thanks to a feature called [Fast Startup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/fast-startup-causes-system-hibernation-shutdown-fail):

> Windows does this by saving the kernel session and device drivers
> (system information) to the hibernate (hiberfil.sys) file on disk
> instead of closing it when you shut down the computer.

Does Ubuntu 20.04 have an equivalent to this feature?

Comment: Ubuntu does have hibernation, check your power options. Need to have a big enough swap partition, or set an offset for a swapfile.

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124476/is-it-possible-to-hybrid-bootfast-startup-ubuntu-like-windows-10) answer your question?

Comment: My only caveat is that Windows also has a hibernation mode that is separate from its shutdown mode. So what gives when it comes to the difference between the two?

Comment: @facialrecognition no it is not. It is Microsoft rebranding "hibernate" and "suspend" to "fast startup". It is the same thing: caching and reloading  what is in memory

Comment: I see, just like Retina Display with Apple: just rebranding similar, if not the same, features. Thank you!